# Using NodaTime Instant in WebAPI model always fails validation

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net, nodatime

One of the models for my WebAPI v4 endpoint has a field of type `NodaTime.Instant`. Model validation always reports that this fails (`Model.IsValid == false`), with the error message "Unexpected token parsing Instant. Expected String, got Date." which is clearly coming from [NodaTime](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/source/browse/src/NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet/NodaDateTimeZoneConverter.cs?spec=svn894f8499b0556e5bd27dd2694c88ef0dc349ba88&r=894f8499b0556e5bd27dd2694c88ef0dc349ba88).

The request message does in fact pass the `Instant` as a string containing an ISO-8601 date, so it must be getting parsed to a BCL `DateTime` at some point before NodaTime gets it. I tried using `OffsetDateTime` and `LocalDateTime`, but got similar errors in each case.

So what should I do here? Should I pass something other than an `Instant`? Is there some other way to handle the parsing or validation that won't cause this error?

I've included a minimal repro below. It should fail if you POST to it with a request body like `{"SomeInstant":"2013-08-13T17:51:22.1705292Z"}`

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using NodaTime;

namespace TestProject.Controllers
{
    /** Assume that we called GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Bcl) in Global.asax.cs **/
    public class NodaTimeController : ApiController
    {
        public Instant Post(TestModel m)
        {
            //ModelState.IsValid is always false due to error parsing the Instant field
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState));
            }
            return m.SomeInstant;
        }
    }

    public class TestModel
    {
        public Instant SomeInstant { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know enough about how Json.NET and WebAPIv4 to know how this is meant to work. If the error message mentions `Date` rather than `DateTime`, it sounds like it may not actually have parsed it, but it's recognized it as a `Date` in JSON. Hmm. Adding the json.net tag as this seems likely to be relevant...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the joys of Twitter, it looks like this is just a matter of disabling the auto-DateTime-handling in Json.NET, e.g.

```
[...]JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None
```

It's possible that we should fix the configuration method to do this automatically...

Note that this will *also* disable the handling of `"Date(...)"` values, so you do need to be careful with it. If you're in complete control of the caller of course, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! I checked and with this setting you can still use BCL DateTime's in the API as long as they're using ISO-8601 formatting. Which all right thinking APIs should be doing anyway.

Comment: Looks like `DateParseHandling` was added in Json.Net 4.5.4.  We built NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet on Json.Net 4.0.8.  We should probably revisit it.